# Magento cart including random products

Tags: php, magento, session, e-commerce, magento-1.5

We have an issue with random products appearing in the Cart/Basket on a Magento 1.5 store.

It only happens in a fresh browser session (FF/IE/Chrome). if you browse the site, add an item to the Cart/Basket, Then when you View the Cart/Basket there are other products in the cart.

The products that get added are NOT product from the Upsell or Related list. They are not products that might have been added in a previous browser session.

We have uninstalled all extensions that we can. There are no IP based extensions installed.

We have set Session Cookie Management to Use HTTP Only = Yes. and Lifetime to 5400 - same as another site that is fine.

Also tried setting `REMOTE_ADDR` and `HTTP_USER_AGENT` set to Yes. (now set back to no)

It does not seem to be Theme based, as when we switch to the modern theme it still happens.

The 'database' was storing the sessions, however we changed this (via the local.xml) to 'file' once the problem was noticed to see if that made a difference - but it didn't.

In the PHP config `session.save_path = tmp` and APC caching is disabled.

Has anyone seen anything like this or suggest any thing futher to check?

Comment: Which modules do you have installed? Must be some observer event which is a causing this..

Comment: I would add stack trace logging into the `addAction` of `/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php` and see where it's coming from. Though I would use the Debug Utils version that Don Briggs [suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423157/print-php-call-stack)

Comment: Hi Gershon - by 'modules' do you mean extensions? i will check but its pretty much back to a standard install now, however i cant be sure any that have been uninstalled have done so completley.

re the Observer Events  - is there a way to monitor / report on these so we can compare to a fresh install of Magento?

Thanks for your input on this

Comment: Thanks CCBlackburn we will have a look at Debug Utils as suggested

Comment: OK - Finally got this resolved (Sonassi assisted with this) we had a clean up SQL script that was run but it left some of the tables with values so we had to clear these also:

mg_sales_flat_quote_address_item
mg_sales_flat_quote_item
mg_sales_flat_quote_item_option
mg_sales_flat_quote_payment

what was happening the flat_quotes_table was referencing old data in the flat_quotes_items table

many thanks for your feedback