# What class/function called the current method?

Tags: php, cakephp, logging

## Question

I've created a logging class and want to stamp each line with the `class::method` that called the static method of the logger class.

Is it possible to tell what called the current method in PHP?

## Solution

Thanks for the help. Here's the PHP code for my logging method.

```
/**
 * Writes a line into the log.
 * @param string $level The logging level.
 * @param string $message The message.
 */
protected static function write($level,$message)
{
    self::scope_init();
    if(self::$scope[$level])
    {
        $e = new Exception;
        $stack = $e->getTrace();
        $caller = '';
        if(isset($stack[2]))
        {
            $class = isset($stack[2]['class']) ? $stack[2]['class'] : false;
            $method =  isset($stack[2]['function']) ? $stack[2]['function'] : '';
            if($class !== false)
            {
                $caller = $class.'::'.$method;
            }
            else
            {
                $caller = $method;
            }
        }

        $caller = substr(str_pad($caller,20),0,20);

        $msg = date('m.d.y h:i:sa').' ['.$level.'] ['.$caller.'] '.$message;
        self::$lines[] = $msg;
        echo "$msg\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This answer about printing stack traces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7039409/931721) gives a way to access the stack trace. From there, you can get just the second-to-last item and record that.

```
$e = new Exception;
var_dump($e->getTraceAsString());

#2 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php(626): SeriesHelperTest->setUp()
#3 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php(666): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
#4 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php(576): PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(Object(SeriesHelperTest))
#5 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(757): PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#6 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php(733): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest(Object(SeriesHelperTest), Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
#7 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php(305): PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult), false, Array, Array, false)
#8 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(188): PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(Object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), Array)
#9 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(129): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(Array, true)
#10 /usr/bin/phpunit(53): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
#11 {main}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use  the [`__METHOD__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constantbinside of the calling method

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this one: [apd-callstack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apd-callstack.php)？

Comment: Sadly, that requires an debug extension that I can't enabled on a production server.