# Get called class name in Another class

Tags: php

we have one class

```
class A
{
    // I am using class B here
   public function whatever()
   {
      $class_b = new B;
      $class_b->show_caller();
   }
}
```

and other

```
class B
{
    public function show_caller()
    {
        // show me the caller class (should output "A")
    }

}
```

I need to get the caller class name.
P.S. Inheritance is not an option!

Comment: Why do you need the caller? Sounds like a design-flaw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print PHP Call Stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423157/print-php-call-stack)

Comment: Well, I know the architecture is bad, but project it's pretty big and i haven't time to refactor all of it. I just can't use Inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Pass class `A` as a parameter to `B::show_caller()` and output it's class name using [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php):

```
class A
{
    // I am using class B here
   public function whatever()
   {
      $class_b = new B;
      $class_b->show_caller($this);
   }
}

class B
{
    public function show_caller($class)
    {
        echo get_class($class);
    }

}
```

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. *How* is it supposed to be dynamic? How wouldn't solution work for you?

Comment: I think he mean that $class_b->show_caller($class_b); will return B, not A. But it's really interesting to find solution without parameters

Answer (score 0):

We can't provide the knowledge about of where your method is executing to method's class without parameters. Late static binding will work only with inheritance, so it's not your case. The only approach, I can give you, is to use your IDE ability to find method usage in your project (`ctrl+mouse1` in PhpStorm). If you're not using any IDE - it's a time to start.