# How to get email failiure stackstrace in PHP

Tags: php, email

I am sending an email from the PHP code. But when I send the email it return the error status. But I do not know how to get the stack trace/error.

Below is the code snippet which I am using.

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message,$headers))
{
    echo "Success.......................";
}
else
{
    echo "Error.......................";
}
```

It says's error.

I want to get a detailed stack trace so I can fix the issue. Please suggest the code snippet to detect if any

Comment: See answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20203870/7321917)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print PHP Call Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423157/print-php-call-stack)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the error message for the mail() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186725/how-can-i-get-the-error-message-for-the-mail-function)