# How to convert debug_stacktrace() into a string?

Tags: php, debugging

I want to send an email with a stack trace. What's a good way to convert `debug_stacktrace()` into a string?

If I do `implode("\n", debug_backtrace()))` I get a repetition of `Array Array Array`, I can also try to make things more complicated, e.g. writing code to handle specific parts, or I can try to capture the output of `debug_print_backtrace` into a variable.

But ideally I'd like a simple solution for this. Is there one?

Comment: `debug_print_backtrace`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423157/print-php-call-stack/7039409#7039409

Answer (score 1):

Some approaches:

```
$debugStr = print_r(debug_backtrace(), true);
echo $debugStr;
// or
ob_start();
debug_print_backtrace();
$debugStr = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know (or forgot) about `print_r`.