# How to debug a class redefinition in PHP?

Tags: php, debugging, stack-trace, require-once

I'm getting a `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Foo in /directory/ on line 20` error, but I have no idea where it's coming from. I'm always using `require_once` for this class file, and I'm not sure how to debug it. Can I get some kind of inclusion stack trace somehow? I'm running PHP 5, so case sensitivity such as descriped here should not be a problem: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159216/how-can-i-get-php-to-produce-a-backtrace-upon-errors

Comment: Unfortunately I can't install PHP extensions. Moreover, debug_backtrace only tells me there's an error on require_once...

Comment: check also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) in file where is class declared, but before it's declaration

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to rename the class that was redefined (also rename the file containing the class) and then fix all class-not-found errors you get from that. That should lead you to the code that is causing the redefinition. In my case it was a class_alias statement that was causing the problem.

Comment: That would have helped me. In my scenario the "cannot redeclare" error was a complete red herring -- the issue was that the autoloader couldn't find some other, unrelated class.