# Better PHP Notices

Tags: php

Is there a way to make php notices more informative? For example, I'm getting notices such as

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/anon/public_html/MotE/lib/Bullet.php on line 18

while running file() to store each line in an array and then exploding each line in the array by \t.  Is there a way to have the notice show me which line in the file I'm reading from is causing the issue?

I would like to know if there is a way to make php notices more informative?

Perhaps something like

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/anon/public_html/MotE/lib/Bullet.php on line 18 [File: /feed.csv]

If I do something like

```
echo 'line: ' . $arrKey . '<br />';
```

the notices all disappear but echoing that much information is undesirable and provides no useful information since the notices disappear.

Comment: what is the question? solving that error? or getting more comprehensive error messages? maybe try xdebug

Comment: In that case, you know it's the *second* item in your array that is the problem (arrays being 0-indexed). Sometimes it's about being familiar with php's sometimes weird messages (Paamayim Nekudotayim anyone?)

Comment: Yes but not every line drops a notice...only certain ones.

Comment: So what you are looking for is error checking - like `if (is_valid_thing($thing)) { do_work(); } else { /* throw a nice error */ }

Comment: Yes that would work if I can find out which line of the feed.csv was being read just before the undefined offseet.

Comment: @nate this notice is very very informative. First i used to think like you but keep on learning these message actually tell you in 90% of the cases what you are doing wrong. undefined offset 1, means that value for index or offset one does not exist. Thanks

Comment: if you post your code i might be able to tell, how to make it disappear without echoing out any thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) - it will print backtrace for you.
More info here: [How can I get PHP to produce a backtrace upon errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159216/how-can-i-get-php-to-produce-a-backtrace-upon-errors)